# List the output in a table form

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a output of

```
Student Name: abc
Roll Num: 123

Student Name: xyz
Roll Num: 124
```

and I need to print in below format

```
Student Name     Roll Num
abc              123
xyz              124
```

can someone help me with simple linux commands

Comment: what would be the output if there were multiple student name `abc` for example either with same Roll Num or different ?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is not the only tool in the toolbox, of course.  Here's [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) in action:

```
% mlr --ixtab --ips : --opprint cat << END
Student Name: abc
Roll Num: 123

Student Name: xyz
Roll Num: 124

END
Student Name Roll Num
 abc          123
 xyz          124
%
```

You are doing a conversion from XTAB format (`-ixtab`) to PPRINT format (`-opprint`).

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F': |\n' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{print $1, $3} {print $2, $4}' file
Student Name    Roll Num
abc     123
xyz     124

$ awk -v RS= -F': |\n' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{print $1, $3} {print $2, $4}' file | column -s$'\t' -t
Student Name  Roll Num
abc           123
xyz           124

$ awk -v RS= -F': |\n' -v fmt='%-13s %-13s\n' 'NR==1{printf fmt, $1, $3} {printf fmt, $2, $4}' file
Student Name  Roll Num
abc           123
xyz           124
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ed Morton, Its showing only for 1 student, what if I have 100 students data... can you help me with that please?

Student Name  Roll Num
abc           123

Comment: There is nothing in my solution that cares about how many students you have. As you can see in my answer it produces the expected output you posted given the sample input you posted (please do try that yourself too). If your real data doesn't actually look like the example you posted then that's the most likely reason why you'd have a problem and if that is the case then you should fix the example in your question to be more truly representative of your real data.

Comment: I tried with the same example and its showing only for one student info out of two. 
I just did copy paste of your commands.

Comment: The ONLY way that can happen is if your data doesn't look like the example you posted. Maybe you're missing newlines or the blank line between the 2 students or something, idk but there is SOMETHING different about the input file you're running the command against vs the input file you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Method1

awk 'BEGIN{print "Student Name";RS="Student Name:"}{print $1}' p.txt| awk '$0 !~ /^$/' >student.txt
awk   'RS="Roll Num"{print $2}' p.txt|sed '/Name/,/^$/d'| awk 'BEGIN {print "Roll Num"}{print $0}' > roll.txt


paste student.txt  roll.txt


output

Student Name     Roll Num
abc              123
xyz              124



 Method2

awk 'BEGIN{print "Student Name"}{if($1 ~ /Student/){print $3}}' p.txt > student.txt

awk 'BEGIN{print "Roll Num"}{if($1 ~ /Roll/){print $3}}' p.txt > roll.txt

paste student.txt  roll.txt


output

Student Name     Roll Num
abc              123
xyz              124
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Praveen,
Its displaying only Student Name  and Roll Num not the data (abc, xyz, 123, 124) under the columns.